# Need alternative code for comparing two array using javascript / node js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
Array1 = ["home.jpg",
 "sun.jpg",
 "flower.jpg",
 "fish.jpg"
];

Array2 = ["home.jpg",
 "kite.jpg",
 "car.jpg",
 "coca.jpg",
"flower.jpg"
];
```

I want to compare Array1 with Array2 and store the data of Array2 which not match with Array1, so here `kite.jpg, car.jpg, coca.jpg` are not present inside Array1 so they should be a result.

I have a code which do distinguish the value which is not present inside Array1 and Array2:

```
let result = Array2.filter(function (n) {
                return !this.has(n);
              }, new Set(Array1));
```

But the problem here is when I am doing `console.log(result);`
output comes like this:

```
["kite.jpg"]
["kite.jpg", "car.jpg"]
["kite.jpg", "car.jpg", "coca.jpg"]
```

I want only output like this:

```
["kite.jpg", "car.jpg", "coca.jpg"]
```

```js
Array1=["home.jpg",
 "sun.jpg",
 "flower.jpg",
 "fish.jpg"];

Array2= ["home.jpg",
 "kite.jpg",
 "car.jpg",
 "coca.jpg",
"flower.jpg"];


let result = Array2.filter(function (n) {
                return !this.has(n);
              }, new Set(Array1));
              
              console.log(result);
```

Here I am getting correct output, but in my system its showing  differently so is there any way I can compare and store element which are different ?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say what's going on in your "system".

Try it this way maybe (basically the same but in a bit simpler form):

```js
const arr1 = new Set(Array1)
const result = Array2.filter(elem => !arr1.has(elem))
```